# Code to print Nth fibonacci number

Tags: java, fibonacci

So this is my assignemt, I have to write a function that accepts a number less than 100 and returns the fibonacci element at that position. I don't understand what is wrong with my code. please note that I wrote only `getFibonacciElementAt` function code

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
public class FibonacciNumber {


    public long getFibonacciElementAt(int index) {

        Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter the number");
        int n= sc.nextInt();
    if(n<0)

        return -1;

        int a=0;
        int b=1;
        int i;
        for(i=2; i<=n; i++)
        {
            int temp=a;
            a=b;
            b=temp;
        }
        return a;
    }

    public void printFibonacciElementAt(int index) {
        System.out.println(getFibonacciElementAt(index));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length != 1) {
            System.out.println("Exactly 1 inputs required.");
            return;
        }

        try {
            int num = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
            FibonacciNumber obj = new FibonacciNumber();

            obj.printFibonacciElementAt(num);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.println("Only integers allowed.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, what makes you *think* there's something wrong with the code?  In what way does it not work as expected?  This sounds like a great opportunity to also familiarize yourself with the use of a debugger, so you can step through the code line by line as it executes and observe the runtime behavior and the changing values of your variables.  When you do this, where does it do something unexpected?

Comment: Or short: you please read [mcve] and then you add the missing parts to your question (by editing and enhancing it)

Comment: change what inside the for loop to this : int temp=b; b=a+b; a=temp;

Comment: Why are you using `int`?  These numbers get rather big quite quickly.  You'll need a data type that can store a wider range of values.

Comment: Well the compiler doesn't show any errors, but when when i run it, prrints "exactly 1 inputs required"

Comment: So are you providing an argument when you run it?

Comment: What are your input parameters and what are the use of those in your program.

Comment: Can you explain why you are the objectives of input parameters in your program. Why are you taking asking for input twice?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so re-posting a better recursive version using memoization so runtime of n<=100 is less than 1 second:

```
public static long getFibonacciElementAt(int n, long[] d) {
    if (n == 0 || n == 1)
        return n;

    if (d[n] == 0)
        d[n] = getFibonacciElementAt(n - 1, d) + getFibonacciElementAt(n - 2, d);

    return d[n];

}
```

But once you call the method just pass a new array of the size n+1 as the following:

```
System.out.println(getFibonacciElementAt(n, new long[n+1]));
```

Comment: That's a good approach +1. And it applies directly the equation of **Fibonacci number** `F_{n}=F_{n-1}+F_{n-2}` .

Comment: Good approach with O(n) space complexity? Even When it can be done in O(1)? @Yahya See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You are just exchanging, not adding the previous two numbers. So try following:

```
int a=0;
int b=1;
int temp;
for(int i=2; i<=n; i++)
{
    temp=a+b;
    a=b;
    b=temp;
}
return b;
```